# struts - text area only allow 3 input lines, each 40 chars in length?

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are 3 lines typed in for eReference(text area name).it should only allow 3 input lines, each 40 chars in length.space also consider as an one char.

```
<td>
 <cong:textarea name="eReference" id="eReference" cols="40" rows="3"
         styleClass="textlabelsBoldForTextBox  textCapsLetter commonClass" 
       value="${lclBlForm.eReference}" style="text-align:left;margin-top:-55px;overflow:hidden;" onkeypress="limitText12(this)"/>
</td>                
</tr>
```

filename - erefer.js

```
  function limitText12(ev){
   var text = $(ev).val();
    //      if(text.length()== 40){
   //         text("\n");
    //     }
      var arr = text.split("\n");

 if(arr.length > 4) {
     alert("You've exceeded the 4 line limit!");
     event.preventDefault(); // prevent characters from appearing
 } else {
     for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
         if(arr[i].length > 40 && i < 3) {
             alert("Length exceeded in line 1, 2, or 3!");
             event.preventDefault(); // prevent characters from appearing
         }
     }
 }
 }
```

Comment: This is not correct - var text = $(ev).val();  Instead use - var text = ev.value;

Comment: ev.value not ev.val ...

Comment: this code is allowing more than 3 lines in textarea. if i start typing first row ,it reaches 41 th char ,then it automatically goes to 41 th char in second row.only 3 rows allowed.total char is 120 .can any one help me now

Comment: note : no need to press enter key in each line(41 and 81 th char automatically goes to next line)

Comment: for example empty textarea , i pressed enter key three times it is allowed. if i pressed 4th time , it cant allowed ,because i need 3 lines input only

Comment: any one help me ASAP

Answer (score 0):

Just increase the textarea size to cols="45".  So that the error prompt will occur in the same line. And compare the array length for greater that 3 and not 4. Then it will allow only 3 lines.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
 function limitText12(ev){

    var text = ev.value;
    var arr = text.split("\n");

    if(arr.length > 3) {
        alert("You've exceeded the 4 line limit!");
        event.preventDefault(); // prevent characters from appearing            
    }
    else {
      for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
          if(arr[i].length > 39) {
              var j =i+1;
              alert("Length exceeded in line " + j);
              event.preventDefault(); // prevent characters from appearing
          }
      }            
    }

  }  


</script>
```

Comment: it will allow only 3 lines.but end of each line i pressed enter key . if i type 41 char ,it automatically goes to next row .

Comment: how to avoid to press enter key ? total char (including space) is 120

Comment: Change arr[i].length > 40 to arr[i].length > 39.  Then it prevents 41st character from being typed. I checked.  It works.

Comment: i think you are not understood my question. in first row i typed 40 char . next i am going to type 41 th char , that time 41 th char it goes to second row . no need to press enter key at the end of first row .

Comment: 1 row is equal to 40 char . then no need to press enter key.if i start type 41  th  char it goes to second row.total 3 rows . total char is 120 .

Comment: once again i will post my full code ...may be it is useful for some one        <td>
                    <cong:textarea name="eReference" id="eReference" cols="45" rows="3"
                                   styleClass="textlabelsBoldForTextBox  textCapsLetter commonClass"
                                   value="${lclBlForm.eReference}" style="text-align:left;margin-top:-55px;overflow:hidden;width:70%;" onkeyup="limitTexts(this)"/>
                </td>

Comment: function limitTexts(ev){
    var text = ev.value;
    text = text.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");
    text = text.replace(/(.{40})/g, "$1\n")
    document.getElementById("eReference").value = text;
    var arr = text.split("\n");
    var lines_removed,char_removed;
  if(arr.length > 3) {
        arr=arr.slice(0,3);
        lines_removed=1
  } else {
      for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
          if(arr[i].length > 40) {
               arr[i]=arr[i].slice(0,120);
               char_removed=1;
          } } }
   if(char_removed||lines_removed)ev.value=arr.join('\n');
  }

Comment: hi 
here user enter 40 char. after entering 40 char ,it allows next line. for example i entered 20 char,then i press enter , it is not allow . so min char is 0, max char is 40 .below 40 char it should accept to press enter key.
thank u in advance